# Cannot use an add operation in a left outer join when the joined table is null. How can I make this work?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

So I tried to make the code below work for MySQL:

```
SELECT ProdDate
       ,PastProdDate
       ,sum(PastQuantity) + sum(ProdQuantity) AS 'Total Quantity'
       ,sum(ProdPrice * ProdQuantity) + sum(PastPrice * PastQuantity) AS 'Total'
FROM supply
LEFT JOIN PastSupply ON Supply.ProdID = PastSupply.ProdIDPast
GROUP BY ProdDate
         ,PastProdDate;
```

It appears that the problem with the code is that if there is nothing in the PastSupply table, the 'Total Quantity' and 'Total' is null as well. I know why this happens, but I am wondering how this might be solved. I tried adding a default value but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Can you post your table structure with some sample data? It might help answer your question.  You can post in sqlfiddle.com if you want.

Comment: I would recommend you start using aliases in your queries. It makes everything a lot simpler, especially when you include the alias for every single column. That way you don't have to guess which table a column belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

Use `COALESCE`:

```
Select ProdDate, 
       PastProdDate,
       coalesce(sum(PastQuantity),0) + 
         coalesce(sum(ProdQuantity),0) as 'Total Quantity', 
       coalesce(sum(ProdPrice * ProdQuantity),0) + 
         coalesce(sum(PastPrice * PastQuantity),0) as 'Total' 
from supply 
left join PastSupply 
   on Supply.ProdID = PastSupply.ProdIDPast 
group by ProdDate,PastProdDate;
```

Comment: Shouldn't each value (ProdPrice, ProdQuantity) be COALESCE:d instead of the whole SUM(...,...)? Just a thought